# preventing a cmdlet from freezing powershell

Tags: powershell

I created a cmdlet that automates keystrokes to window. When I attached that window to the debugger and perform long debugging operations, powershell freezes and even ctrl+c is not recognized.

Can you help me with this? thanks :)

Comment: You really are going to have to share your cmdlets source code, or at least enough to allow us to produce the error to get any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start a background-job (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878288(v=vs.85).aspx).
You can work while your command is executed in the background and look at the results with receive-job or look at the status with get-job).